# windows 10 machine restarted and applications removed and we windows.old folder

Tags: windows, updates

Windows 10 machine was restarted and it installed some updates and any additional applications installed (non windows default) are no longer installed.  We have a specific business application called unity we wish to get working.  The icons are on the desktop but not installed.  We also have a Windows.old folder on the c drive.  The folder contents are :

PerfLogs
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
Recovery
Users
Windows

How do I find out what happened?  and how do I correct the issue so I can open the additional applications installed?

Comment: It looks like it was a feature update which means a new Windows build/version. What additional applications (you think) are no longer installed? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: added comments, the application is not a common program.  its a local ERP system application.  Why would a feature remove a application.  We have backups going back 2 weeks which work but every restore point starts the upgrades.  Is there any way to stop the windows feature updates?

Comment: Why would a feature remove a application.   .... Feature Updates may remove Applications that are no longer compatible. That is what happened here. Generally, you cannot stop updates so you need to fix or replace the application.

Comment: how do i know/prove the app isnt compatible? I've never seen this behavior before

Comment: You probably cannot "prove it"  .  Try rolling back the update. It may already be too late.  .....   I've never seen this behavior before  ...  I have seen this numerous times.

Comment: I'm not dismissing what your saying, just my personal experience I haven't seen it.  I'll need to convince the software house that developed this app that his app isn't compatible with windows 10.....im sure how to do this.  Is there some sort of log that windows creates to say why they moved their app to windows.old? ]

Comment: What happens if you actually INSTALL the app after the removal?  If I understand correctly, you are trying to fix this and not solve a nancy drew mystery.

Comment: your right, i want it solved but i also dont want it to happen again.  The external company will have to install the app.  I don't know how to install it.  They will charge to re-install but I don't know if there software is at fault or Windows update has gone haywire.

Comment: "how do i know/prove the app isn't compatible?" - A log file should have been generated that indicates which applications were uninstalled.  You should be able to restore the backup, then go into set the group policy, to avoid the next feature update.  However, if you are on a version of Windows 10 that has expired, you really should address that significant issue.  Since you provide little to no information about your install this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which log  and its location so i can have a look?  I can post the details back here.  What details about the install would you need?